# Best Practice for Folder Structure For Resolvers and TypeDefs resolve ambiguity

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am working on best practices for folder structure on an apollo-graphql project. Right now I have a graphql folder that contains both a Resolvers and Schema Folder, this is to keep everything separate. However, Within my Resolvers folder I want a new Typescript file for each Typedef. (See photo)

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

However, in my Index file I put in this

/src/graphql/resolvers/index.ts

```
export *from "./Category"
export * from "./Product"
```

However, I get the following error
"./Category" has already exported a member named 'resolvers'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity."

What is the best way to approach this issue so that I can have everything separated out, but still only have to import one line into my ApolloServer

src/index.ts

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
import { context } from './graphql/context'
import {typeDefs} from "./graphql/Schema/index"
import {resolvers} from "./graphql/resolvers/index"


new ApolloServer({ resolvers, typeDefs, context: context }).listen(
    { port: 4000 },
    () =>
      console.log(`
   Server ready at: http://localhost:4000`))
```